# Css Halfscreen image

Tags: html, css

Here is my problem(want to make that kind of thing):

[image]

1. Half screen image and half screen text;
2. That block with image and paragraph must be 50% of page;
   Here is my code

```css
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <img src="media/images/pexels-photo-316465.jpeg" alt="#" class="img-responsive">
  <p>sample text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in your css

```
float:left;
```

However; if you'd like it to be in a nicer format, you should use bootstrap which will also let you divide your layout into two section side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS instead:

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.info {
  font-size: 0;
}

.info img,
.info p {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/3372/

Comment: thx, that works http://prntscr.com/j53hdu now i should make it responsible